# Rose King's Shield temp HP does it stack?

Tags: dnd-4e

I am using a Elf Swordmage at the moment, and have given him a feat called

**Rose King's Shield**

**Prerequisite**: Avenger or Swordmage, proficiency with longsword

**Benefit:** You gain a +2 feat bonus to Endurance checks. Once per turn when you hit an enemy with an attack power associated with this feat while using a longsword, you gain 5 temporary hit points. If you ended your turn more than 2 squares away from where you started, you instead gain 10 temporary hit points.

**Associated Powers:** Booming Blade, Focused Fury

My question is, do these temp hit points stack during an encounter? i.e. if you hit someone with that associated power several times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Temporary hit points do not stack. You take the higher of the number of THP you have left and the number granted to you.

From the [compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=glossary&id=340):

> If you get temporary hit points and already have some, use the higher value as your temporary hit point total instead of adding the values together.

Comment: yea, i was thinking that would be way to powerfull.. I dont think my dm was listening when I asked him that question he said yes.. but hes a busy guy so I'll forgive him.. Still though thats a really powerfull feat imo.. so long as your hitting your getting temp hp, sorta like a buffer. I will accept your answer once the time is up.. thanks very much.. I friken love this exchange :)

Comment: @C.Johns yes a lot of the feat support for At-wills is quite good.